# switching a website to the new CMS

Tags: apache

I have been asked to update a site to a new version of a popular CMS. The new site is almost ready, and Im wondering how to limit downtime during the switch.

I have a folder [/public_html] that holds the current site. Im thinking I can make a new folder [/public_html2], copy the new site into there, test it, then simply rename the folders

[`/public_html`] -> [`/public_html_old`]

and

[`/public_html2`] -> [`/public_html`]

and downtime would be the time it takes me to rename the folders.

Is this the 'right' way to do it? is it bad?, is there a 'better' way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe u could just change the config for this project on apache. Making the downtime only the time to restart the apache. I think it will be smaller.